# Using Linked list rendering/Processing loop for multiple object types

Tags: android, linked-list

So, Iv just recently switched over from c++ to java for android programing, and this may be a simple fix but I haven't been able to figure it out yet :( (and yes iv tried searching, although not 100% sure on the correct lingo, so may have missed it)

Pretty much, Iv got a

```
public static LinkedList<Object> LList = new LinkedList<Object>();
```

Defined that is used for rendering and animating objects. The problem is because I have just 1 linked list, and multiple object types I need to use if(LList.get(i) instanceof ship) for each object type.

For example

```
int i;   
    if(LList.size()>=1)
    {
        for(i=0;i<LList.size();i++)
        {
            if(LList.get(i) instanceof ship)
                ((ship) LList.get(i)).animate(elapsedTime);
            else if(LList.get(i) instanceof Laser)
                ((Laser) LList.get(i)).animate(elapsedTime);
        } 
    }
```

Call me crazy, but this does not seem like it is the best way. It works...but in c++ all you would simply have to do is make both ship and laser have the same parent then you could call .animate without worrying about the (ship/laser) typecast.

Is there a way to do this in java? I tried the same way as you would in c++ but that didn't seem to work. keep in mind im new to java, so may have simply done it wrong.

I was although thinking that I could modify the LList.add function so you also pre-define the objects type as you add it, that would get rid of the instanceof problem, but not really add any flexibility.

Anyway, Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. The easiest is to define either a base class or an interface that defines the common functionality of all objects in your list. For instance, you might have:

```
public interface Animatable {
    public void animate(long elapsedTime);
}

public class Ship implements Animatable {
    public void animate(long elapsedTime) {
        // implementation for Ship
    }
}

// etc for other classes
```

Then you could write:

```
public static LinkedList<Animatable> LList = new LinkedList<Animatable>();

// ...

for (Animatable object : LList) {
    object.animate(elapsedTime);
}
```

The same basic pattern would apply if you wanted to use a common base class, with the difference that if there was behavior that had a common implementation in all classes, it could be factored out into the base class.

Another approach is to use the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). Although that is a bit harder to understand at first, it provides for much more flexibility and extensibility over the approach outlined above.

Comment: Oh cool, so it pretty much is the same as I used to do in c++. Thanks! just didnt know that implements was how parents-childs were defined, Thanks!

Comment: `implements` is how to define the relationship between a class and interfaces. (An interface is similar to a pure abstract class in C++, albeit with some important differences.) Use `extends` to define inheritance between classes. Unlike C++, Java allows only single inheritance (a class can have only one superclass). However a class can implement any number of interfaces.